# is there anyway in java to see if a variable matches a list of words?

Tags: java, list, variables

is there any way in java that i can check a list of words to see if a variable matches any of them, and if it does I want to increment a counter.  I know I create a lot of if statements but I think a list of some sort would make the program easier to navigate.
For example if variable 1 is equal to any in the list increment positive value.

```
String  vbl1 = "happy";
```

then i would have a few lists like:

```
list 1: 

joyful
great
excited
happy
```

thanks in advance guys.

Comment: a regular expression might do the trick.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to implement this. Of course, some are better than others but still, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, perhaps with something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] words = { "joyful", "great", "excited",
      "happy" };
  java.util.List<String> list1 = java.util.Arrays
      .asList(words);
  String vbl1 = "happy";
  if (list1.contains(vbl1)) {
    System.out.printf("%s contains %s\n",
        java.util.Arrays.toString(words), vbl1);
  } else {
    System.out.printf("%s does not contain %s\n",
        java.util.Arrays.toString(words), vbl1);
  }
}
```

Which outputs

```
[joyful, great, excited, happy] contains happy
```

Answer (score 3):

Use java.util.List or any other datastructure that implements java.util.Collection. As suggested in comments, java.util.Set may suit better if ordering does not matter.

You can check if a given items exists in the list by using contains() method.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("joyful");
list.add("great");
list.add("excited");
list.add("happy");
boolean contains = list.contains("happy");
```

Comment: A Set would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: If all you need is the `contains` method, I'd suggest a compile-time type of `Collection<String>` with a runtime type of `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring case you can do

```
list.contains(yourWord)
```

This will return true if there is a match so you can increment your counter then.

If you want to consider case I think the clearest way will be to loop through the list and calling equals on each item in the list

Edit: as per comment in another answer a set may be cleaner and more efficient as it will remove any duplicates you have in your list (although won't guarantee an order
)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words  = { "joyful", "great", "excited","happy" };
String matchStr = "happy"; 
for(String i:words){
     if(i.equals(matchStr)){
           // Increment Counter Here
     }
}
```